# Connecting to MySQL through PHP, JSON error

Tags: android

I wrote a simpe PHP script that prints an jsonencode($output). It outputs the JSON with a leading and ending []. When I run my Android program through the emulaotor, it states: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of [..... then lists my JSON, so I know its getting the data, there is a problem with the decode process that its not removing those square brackets. Here is the function that is throwing the error to the log:

```
   public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your JSon response looks like: `[{'name':'value'},...]`

Your JSon Object must begin with `{` like the error message says. It should be:
`{'my_array':[.......]}`

Then you could write: `new JSONObject().getJSONArray("my_array");`

Comment: But the default print(jsonencode($output)); from PHP is formatted without a title and with square brackets. no way to change this.